# ngx-mapbox-gl button click event inside a popup is not triggered

Tags: angular7, mapbox-gl-js

I'm rending map using this angular library for mapbox [ngx-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl)
I'm showing a popup on mouseenter event.

```
mapInstance.on("mouseenter", "scoots_layers", function (e) {
  var _lat = e.lngLat.lat;
  var _lng = e.lngLat.lng;
  var coordinates = [_lng, _lat];
  this.popup = new Popup({
    closeButton: true,
    closeOnClick: true,
  });
  this.popup.setLngLat(coordinates)
    .setHTML('<button (click)="goToPage()">Hello </button>')
    .addTo(mapInstance);
});
```

Popup is working fine. But the click event of button is not triggered.

Comment: Can you give us the goToPage() code

Comment: goToPage() {
    alert('say something...');
  }

it's inside map.component.ts

Comment: There's an answer similar to this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61511189/adding-a-button-to-the-popup-in-mapboxgl-js/64182029#64182029

Answer (score 2):

Maybe if you do it this way it works

```
 this.popup.setLngLat(coordinates)
.setHTML('<button  id="myBtn">Hello </button>')
.addTo(mapInstance);
```

});

and in your ts file

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert('say something...');
});
```