# Redirect to angular component from Mapbox popup

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, mapbox-gl-js, ionic5

I am developing a mobile application using Ionic and Angular. I have several Mapbox markers rendered on the map, each of it displaying a popop on click with custom content. I would like the button in the popup to redirect the user to the page that contains more details about that specific location. My code is the following:

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.businessService
    .getBusinessCoords()
    .subscribe(data=>{
      for(const key in data){
        let popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
          className:'popup-class'
        }).setHTML(
            `<div>
            <img src= ${data[key].profile_picture} width="150">
            <b style="text-align: center;"> ${data[key].name}</b><br>
            <i>${data[key].location.address}</i><br>
            <a id="${key}">Tap to see availble offers!</a>
            </div>
            `
          )
        new mapboxgl.Marker({
          color:"#cc0000",
          draggable: false
        }).setLngLat([data[key].location.coord.lng, data[key].location.coord.lat])
          .setPopup(popup)
          .addTo(this.map);
      }
    })//end subscribe
  }
```

Of course that the ready-to-use method would be using the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag, but I would like to use some Angular-specific routing method to route to the respective page of each business displayed on the map (the route should depend on the ${key}). So far I have tried using `document.getElementByClassName("some-test-class")[0].addEventListener('click',()=>{console.log("hello!"});` after adding the `some-test-class` class to the `<a>` tag and something similar with `document.getElementById()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56088473/ngx-mapbox-gl-button-click-event-inside-a-popup-is-not-triggered) and [in the 3rd answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61511189/adding-a-button-to-the-popup-in-mapboxgl-js/64182029#64182029) and I get "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined". I also tried the second approach listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460579/angular-2-leaflet-map-how-to-link-to-a-component-from-marker-popup-rout) but this does not seem to work either. I also saw more complex solutions, that involve `ComponentFactoryResolver` (the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48229709/mapbox-gl-popup-set-content-with-custom-tag)) but before trying to wrap my head around it just to solve what seems to be something trivial, I thought of asking for an easier, more-direct approach. Or maybe for a suggestion of why my previous attempts failed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved it using the first answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61511189/adding-a-button-to-the-popup-in-mapboxgl-js/64182029#64182029). My code now:

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.businessService
    .getBusinessCoords()
    .subscribe(data=>{
      for(const key in data){
        const popupContent = document.createElement('div');
        popupContent.innerHTML = `<img src= ${data[key].profile_picture} width="150">
                                  <b style="text-align: center;"> ${data[key].name}</b><br>
                                  <i>${data[key].location.address}</i><br>`;
        const atag = document.createElement('div');
        atag.innerHTML = `<a id="${key}">Tap to see availble offers!</a>`
        popupContent.appendChild(atag); 
        atag.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
          console.log('Button was clicked' + key);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/foodrevolution/profile')
        })
        let popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
        }).setDOMContent(popupContent); 
          
        new mapboxgl.Marker({
          color:"#cc0000",
          draggable: false
        }).setLngLat([data[key].location.coord.lng, data[key].location.coord.lat])
          .setPopup(popup)
          .addTo(this.map);
      }
    })//end subscribe
  }
```

where `router` is of type `Router` from `@angular/router`. This thing seems to work even if I use `ionViewWillEnter`, so I am not sure if the choice of a lifecycle hook makes a diference here.

Answer (score 3):

There is another option when using `mapboxgl.Source` and `mapboxgl.Layer` for your data.

1. Transform your data into GeoJson such that the dynamic content for the popups is stored in the features `properties`.
2. Create a [`mapboxgl.Source` with `type: "geojson"`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/sources/#geojsonsource) using your transformed GeoJson data.
3. Create a `mapboxgl.Layer` with the created source and your preferred style.
4. Add a popup container in your component template that is then referenced in the `setDOMContent` method. See below for some prototyping.

This allows you to fully interact between the Popup and Angular (not just the routing).

```html
<!-- component.html -->
<div #popupContainer class="popup-container">
  <div *ngIf="popup">
    <img [src]="popup.profile_picture" width="150">
    <b style="text-align: center;">{{ popup.name }}</b><br>
    <i>{{ popup.location.address }}</i><br>
    <a routerLink="/foodrevolution/profile">Tap to see availble offers!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
// component.ts
@ViewChild("popupContainer") popupContainer: any;
popup: any;

ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.businessService
    .getBusinessCoords()
    .subscribe((data) => {
      const geoJson = toGeoJson(data);
      this.map.getSource("source-id").setData(geoJson);
    });
  this.map.on("click", "points-layer", (e) => {
    const coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
    this.popup = e.features[0].properties;
    new mapboxgl.Popup()
      .setLngLat(coordinates)
      .setDOMContent(this.popupContainer.nativeElement)
      .addTo(this.map);
  });
}
```

A single Feature in the GeoJson FeatureCollection should more or less look like this

```
{
  type: "Feature",
  geometry: {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [
      data[key].location.coord.lng,
      data[key].location.coord.lat
    ]
  },
  properties: {
    key: key,
    name: data[key].name
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call any htmlElement in ionViewWillEnter as the view isn't created.
Try to put this code into ionViewDidEnter instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that was not the issue. I eventually solved it.